# 自作クラスでEXC_BREAKPOINT messaage sent to deallocated instanceのエラー

Tags: ios, swift

下記のようにIn App Perpose用の`StoreObesrver`クラスを作成しました。

しかし、"EXC_BREAKPOINT"、"messaage sent to deallocated instance"のエラーがでてしまいます。
原因はdelagate関連だと思っているのですが、解決方法が分かりません。

ご教示よろしくお願い致します

---

### error

xcode

[image]

console

[image]

---

### StoreObserver.swift

```
public class StoreObserver: NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    var productRequest:SKProductsRequest?
    var productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects: "com.xxx.xxx")

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func canPayment() {
        if !SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            showAlertView("Setting Error", message: "check your setting")
            return
        }
        productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<NSObject>)
        productRequest?.delegate = self
        productRequest?.start()
        }

    } // ここを出るとエラーがでます。

    public func productsRequest(request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        println("fail get")
    }

    public func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("get item data")
     }

     func showAlertView(title:String,message:String){
        var alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = title
        alert.message = message
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
    }

    deinit {
        productRequest?.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: `canPayment()`の`}`がひとつ余分な気がします。`StoreObserver`自体を管理している場所では、このインスタンスを強参照で保持しているのでしょうか？

Comment: まずコンパイルできるコードを載せろよ。`#import StoreKit`がない、`}`がひとつ多い、必須メソッド`paymentQueue`がない。解放済みのオブジェクトにメッセージ送ったっつーエラーなんだからこのインスタンスを使ってる方のコードがねーとわからねーだろ